# ReCAPTCHA validation

Tags: javascript, validation, recaptcha

Here I have a simple form in jsp. I want both the reCAPTCHA and the textbox to be 'required' fields. Currently, if I just fill in text box and press 'Sign In', it still sends data. How do I make the reCAPTCHA required i.e. compulsory?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

<label> Form </label>

<form action = "somefile" method = "post">

  <input = "text" name = "textbox1" required>

  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdliBkTAAAAALmMlPRRm0NtKW3fz2kT2nxiWrVG"></div>

  <button type="submit" name="login">Sign In</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [*Read the documentation*](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024), you have to test sever side or view the response from the server after submitting the form, you can't check beforehand (otherwise it would be pretty simple to defeat).

Comment: What does this have to do with the jQuery Validate plugin?  Please only use tags that reflect the content of your question; anything else is considered tag-spam.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely make the reCaptcha required with some javascript. Of course you still need to verify the reCaptcha server side but this will add some client side validation.

- You need some javascript variable to keep track of whether your reCaptcha has been solved:

  ```
  var captcha_passed = false;
  ```
- Tell Google's reCaptcha to call your function upon successful completion:

  ```
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="on_captcha_filled" data-sitekey="6LdliBkTAAAAALmMlPRRm0NtKW3fz2kT2nxiWrVG"></div>
  ```
- Add a label to let your users know that this was missed. Make it hidden. The javascript will unhide it if they submit without the reCaptcha.

  ```
  <label id="lblCaptchaRequired" style="color: red" hidden>Please complete the reCaptcha</label>
  ```
- Add javascript function to be called by the reCaptcha:

  ```
  function on_captcha_filled() {
      captcha_passed = true;
      document.getElementById("lblCaptchaRequired").hidden = true;
  }
  ```
- Add an onsubmit handler to your form to verify that the reCaptcha has passed before continuing:

  ```
  <form action = "somefile" method = "post" onsubmit = "check_captcha(event)">
  ```
- Add the onsubmit handler javascript:

  ```
  function check_captcha(e) {
      if (captcha_passed)
          return true;
      document.getElementById("lblCaptchaRequired").hidden = false;
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  ```
- Updated form:

  ```
  <form action = "somefile" method = "post" onsubmit = "check_captcha(event)">

      <input = "text" name = "textbox1" required>

      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="on_captcha_filled" data-sitekey="6LdliBkTAAAAALmMlPRRm0NtKW3fz2kT2nxiWrVG"></div>
      <label id="lblCaptchaRequired" style="color: red" hidden>Please complete the reCaptcha</label>

      <button type="submit" name="login">Sign In</button>

  </form>
  ```
- Javascript file

  ```
  var captcha_passed = false;

  /*
  *   Form onsubmit handler.
  *   Display captcha required label and prevent submit until captcha_passed is true
  */
  function check_captcha(e) {
      if (captcha_passed)
          return true;
      document.getElementById("lblCaptchaRequired").hidden = false;
      e.preventDefault();
  }

  /*
  *   Google reCaptcha data-callback handler.
  *   Sets captcha_passed to true to allow form submission and hides captcha required label.
  */
  function on_captcha_filled() {
      captcha_passed = true;
      document.getElementById("lblCaptchaRequired").hidden = true;
  }
  ```

Now when your user reaches that page, the required label is initially hidden and your `captcha_passed` is initialized to `false`. When the user submits the form the onsubmit handler `check_captcha` is called which checks the `captcha_passed` flag and either allows the submit action to continue or stops it and unhides the label.
When the user completes the reCaptcha your `on_captcha_filled` function gets called which sets the `captcha_passed` flag to `true` and hides the label.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the detailed solution below for client-side validation

HTML form:I have added text box google-response and created three call back events.1)data-error-callback="wrongCaptcha", 2)data-callback="correctCaptcha", 3)data-expired-callback="wrongCaptcha",

```
<form class="form-inline" class="text-center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="newsletter-email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="validationNewsletter()">Submit</button>
   <input type="hidden" id="google-response"/>
   <br/><br/>
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" id="gcaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXX-XXXX" data-error-callback="wrongCaptcha" data-callback="correctCaptcha" data-expired-callback="wrongCaptcha"></div>
                </div>
</form>
```

JS Validation

```
  <script>
   function validationNewsletter() {
    if($('#google-response').val()==""||$("[name=g-recaptcha-response]").val()==""){
       alert("Please check google recaptcha");
      return false;
    }
    if($('#google-response').val()!=$("[name=g-recaptcha-response]").val()){
        alert("Sorry spammer");   
        return false;
    }
   if(letsPutFormValidation){
   alert("Some form validation");   
        return false;
  }
  $('#form-id').submit();
 }

 var correctCaptcha = function (response) {
    $('#google-response').val(response);
 };

  var wrongCaptcha=function(response){
    $('#google-response').val('');
  }
</script>
```